# Why are em dashes used here instead of commas?

Tags: em-dash

> Arutyunyan quickly saw promise in the young Chen, but he knew that the boy’s parents — Chinese immigrants who had arrived in the United States in the late 1980s — did not have the resources to finance an expensive elite skating career.

I read this in [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/02/09/sports/olympics/nathan-chen-wins-gold-figure-skating.html) in yesterday’s news, why is em dash used, can comma not be used?

Comment: The _two_ dashes emphasise the phrase explaining the parents' circumstances. Parentheses ( ) could have been used instead, or commas, but if commas were used it wouldn't be so clear that it was an explanatory phrase inserted into the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, em dashes are often interchangeable with commas when used with interrupters. However, they tend to convey different tones. Em dashes convey a more sudden and stark break of rhythm, as if there was a complete stop and break before the interrupter, whereas commas tend to convey a more continuous rhythm. The pauses implied by commas are more natural and briefer.

Comment: Moreover, in modern taste, a sentence can quickly feel overwhelmed by commas, while emdashes — by virtue of their fewer different roles — convey the structure more clearly.

Comment: Plus, although it's not necessarily great style - but occasionally (and awkwardly) unavoidable - to nest subordinate clauses, it's a useful way to differentiate the interruptions.

I used commas, dashes, and parenthesis in that previous sentence for the same basic purpose. It's awkward and a little clumsy, and certainly wouldn't be my first choice of style, but it allows the reader to separate the interruptions.